# Browser plugin for measuring PDF

Tags: plugin, pdf, browsers, measure

Is there a browser plugin that can allow a user to measure objects on a PDF in the browser window? It needs to be cross-browser.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are measuring?

Comment: This should be on superuser.

Comment: This is a cross post from StackOverflow...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480157/browser-plugin-for-measuring-pdf

Comment: And Superuser (http://superuser.com/questions/223520/browser-plugin-for-measuring-pdf) and Web Apps (http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/10463/browser-plugin-for-measuring-pdf)

Answer (score 2):

Change the PDF viewer you are using to one that has a measuring tool in it.  For example, [PDF-XChange Viewer](http://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-viewer).